# wordpress custom query to select a meta value

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
SELECT b.post_title, a.post_id, COUNT( * ) as Total
FROM  wp_posts b INNER JOIN 
            wp_postmeta a ON a.post_id = b.ID
    WHERE a.meta_value = 1
      AND a.meta_key = 'type-select' 
      AND b.post_status = 'publish'
      and post_type = 'car-cc'
GROUP BY b.post_title, a.post_id
```

Currently it select's `post title` and `post id` but i also need to select a `meta value` where **meta key = type-gen** the problem is another meta key is already compared in the query.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/109c2/1

Comment: Why not just create an instance of [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)? - That's what it is there for.

Comment: I was not aware of it at the beginning because of the nature of the plugin.

Comment: There are quite a few situations where you can't use WP_Query (in my case it's because I'm amalgamating results with a table of my own) so this is still a useful question.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go

```
SELECT b.post_title, a.post_id, COUNT( * ) AS Total,
(SELECT meta_value FROM  `wp_postmeta` WHERE post_id= b.ID AND meta_key='type-gen') AS 'new  meta value'
FROM  wp_posts b INNER JOIN 
            wp_postmeta a ON a.post_id = b.ID
    WHERE a.meta_value = 1
      AND a.meta_key = 'type-select' 
      AND b.post_status = 'publish'
      AND post_type = 'car-cc'
GROUP BY b.post_title, a.post_id
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/109c2/7)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.post_title, a.post_id, COUNT( * ) as Total
FROM  wp_posts b INNER JOIN 
            wp_postmeta a ON a.post_id = b.ID
    WHERE (a.meta_value = 1
      AND a.meta_key = 'type-select' 
      AND b.post_status = 'publish'
      and post_type = 'car-cc') 
    OR (a.meta_value = 1
      AND a.meta_key = 'type-gen' 
      AND b.post_status = 'publish'
      and post_type = 'car-cc')
GROUP BY b.post_title, a.post_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for this,

Modified from the [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'car-cc',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'type-select',
      'value' => '1',
      'compare' => '='
),
    array(
      'key' => 'type-gen',
      'value' => 'my-great-type',
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
  )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```